# How are Christoffel symbols explicitly computed?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

In Tu's book on differential geometry he says:

> Let $\nabla$ be an affine connection on a manifold $M$ and let $(U, x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ be a coordinate open set in $M$. Denote by $\partial_i$ the coordinate vector field $\partial/\partial x^i$. Then $\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j$ is a linear combination of $\partial_1, \ldots, \partial_n$, so there exist numbers $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ at each point such that $$\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j = \sum_{k=1}^n \Gamma_{ij}^k \partial_k. \tag{1}$$ These $n^3$ functions $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ are called the **Christoffel symbols** of the connection $\nabla$ on the coordinate open set $(U, x^1, \ldots, x^n)$. By the $\mathcal{F}$-linearity in the first argument of a connection, the Christoffel symbols completely describe a connection on $U$.

I have two questions about this passage,

1. Wouldn't we also need the linearity of the *second* argument of a connection to completely determine a connection on $U$? This allows us to write the connection of a vector field $Y$ along a vector field $X$ as $$\nabla_X Y = \sum_{i,j} \nabla_{x^i\partial_i}{y^j \partial_j}$$ so that each term in this sum has its own expansion (1).
2. How are the Christoffel symbols computed in practice? I originally thought that the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma$ is a tensor with the notation $$\Gamma_{ij} \equiv \Gamma(\partial_i, \partial_j).$$ However based on other questions I have read on here, this seems to be the incorrect formula on how $\Gamma$ is computed. How does $\Gamma$ explicitly depend on $i$ and $j$?

Comment: 1.  Yes but that is presumably assumed.  2. That is a strange question.  If you are talking about Levi-Civita we have Koszul formula.  For other connections (e.g. Chern connection for holomorphic vector bundles, or a connection arising from a $G$-structure) you either have similar formula or you know enough about its parallel transport to find $\Gamma_{ij}^k$.

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading an undergraduate text on curves and surfaces. And, by the way, the Christoffel symbols are *not* components of a tensor.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I think I should consult an undergraduate textbook to get a feel for some of the concepts I think the abstraction is what is making it difficult. Are there any you recommend that cover the Christoffel symbols?

Comment: @user10354138 I am talking about general manifolds (not necessarily Riemannian). I think another way to phrase my question on the $i$ an $j$ dependence on $\Gamma_{ij}$ is why do we have it in that order? In other words, why not $\Gamma_{ji}$? Is this just convention or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: You can look at my text, freely available at the link on my profile. If you want tensor notation, try Milman and Parker.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you.

Comment: And volume 2 of Spivak’s 5-volume differential geometry opus will relate all the versions of connections to one another.

Comment: use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#General_definition for orientation of your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

This is Levi-Civita connection.

Given a coordinate system, $\{x^\alpha\}$ you can represent the vector space having basis vectors  $\partial _\alpha$. This is short hand for $\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x^a}$ where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector.

Another common representation is $\vec{e_\alpha}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x^\alpha}$

Vectors at some position can be presented as the sum of products of the components of the vector with the basis vectors.

So $\vec{V}=\sum_{\alpha =0}^n V^\alpha\vec{e_\alpha}$

The basis vectors change with position, so do vector components, so it isn't sufficient just to take the derivative of the components.

$\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial x^ \beta}=\sum_{\alpha =0}^n \frac{\partial V^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta}\vec{e_\alpha}+\sum_{\alpha =0}^nV^\alpha\frac{\partial \vec{e_\alpha}}{\partial x^\beta}$

You need the derivative of the components and the derivative of the  basis vectors.

Derivatives of the basis vectors are themselves vectors that can be expressed as components times the same basis vetors.

$\frac{\partial \vec{e_\alpha}}{\partial x^\beta}=\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha \beta}\vec{e_\gamma}$

By this definition, the Christtofel Symbol is the $\gamma$ component of the $\beta$ derivative of the $\alpha$ basis vector .

But keep in mend $\vec{e_\alpha}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x^\alpha}$ so $\frac{\partial \vec{e_\alpha}}{\partial x^\beta}=\frac{\partial^2 \vec{r}}{\partial x^\alpha \partial x^\beta}=\frac{\partial ^2 \vec{r}}{\partial x^\beta \partial x^\alpha}$

So $\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha \beta}=\Gamma^\gamma_{\beta \alpha}$

So the full vector derivative is:

$\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial x^\beta} = \sum_{\alpha =0}^n \frac{\partial V^\alpha}{x^\beta}\vec{e_\alpha}+\sum_{\alpha=0}^n V^\alpha \frac{\vec{e_\alpha}}{x^\beta}=\sum_{\alpha =0}^n \frac{\partial V^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta}\vec{e_\alpha}+\sum_{\alpha=0}^n\sum_{\gamma=0}^nV^\alpha \Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha \beta}\vec{e_\gamma}$

Regarding calculating the Christoffel Symbols, which it should be noted are not tensor coordinates, you can use the definition.

$\frac{\partial \vec{e_\alpha}}{\partial \beta}=\sum _{\gamma=0}^n \Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}\vec{e_\gamma}=  \frac{\partial^2 \vec{r}}{\partial \alpha \partial \beta}$

$\frac{\partial \vec{e_\alpha}}{\partial \beta}\cdot \vec{e_\mu}=\sum _{\gamma=0}^n \Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}\vec{e_\gamma}\cdot \vec{e_\mu}= \frac{\partial^2 \vec{r}}{\partial \alpha \partial \beta} \cdot \vec{e_\mu}$

$g_{\alpha \beta}=\vec{e_\alpha}\cdot \vec{e_\beta}$ is the metric.

$\sum_{\gamma=0}^n \Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha \beta}g_{\mu \gamma}=\frac{\partial ^2 \vec{r}}{\partial \alpha \partial \beta}\cdot \vec{e_\mu}$

And this implies a series of linear equatiosn from which you can figure out the  Christoffel Symbols.

So you can use the definition, or that linear relation.

---

Here's some more intro details: [Christoffel Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols)

Comment: This discussion only applies to Riemannian manifolds isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and not the abstract ones covered by Tu.

Comment: What is "the vector space of unit vectors"?

Comment: Sorry, was supposed to be "basis vectors". Unit vectors work, too,  though better to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

That, while $$\nabla_XY=\nabla_{\sum_iX^i\partial_i}\left(\sum_jY^j\partial_j\right),$$
$$=\sum_iX^i\left(\nabla_{\partial_i}\left(\sum_jX^j\partial_j\right)\right),$$
in the other hand, being  a **Leibnizian**'s operation, it complies
$$\nabla_XY=\nabla_{X}\left(\sum_jY^j\partial_j\right),$$
$$=\sum_j\nabla_{X}\left(Y^j\partial_j\right),$$
$$=\sum_j(\nabla_{X}Y^j)\partial_j+\sum_jY^j(\nabla_{X}\partial_j).$$

Now, if you can asure that the tangent space can be imbued with a differentiable metric (bilinear, symmetric, positive defined and non-degenerated) map $g:T_pM\times T_pM\to\mathbb R$,
then for the coordinated basis $\partial_i$ one constructs the metric tensor
$g_{ij}=g(\partial_i,\partial_j)$. This matrix, at $p$ covered by $U$, would be invertible, having inverse matrix $[g^{ij}]$. Then, at least in the coordinated patch
$$\Gamma^k{}_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_sg^{ks}
(\partial_j g_{is}+\partial_ig_{sj}-\partial_sg_{ij}),$$
accurately.

Comment: OP is explicitly asking for general affine connections, not Levi-Civita connections associated with a Riemannian metric

Comment: @Didier In a finite dimensional tangent space can one not have a differentiable bilinear map to the purpose? forgive my "ignari"

Comment: Not all affine connections arise as Levi-Civita connections: a first obstruction is that such connections need to be torsion-free. The formula you gave is valid only for **the** Levi-Civita connection of the metric $g$.

Comment: Ah! many thanks to you

Comment: @janmarqz Thank you for your answer though.